# Jquery - find which radio was checked and trigger a click for the sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

i have a simple markup, where i would like to loop thro checkboxes states and see which one was checked upon which the final trigger button outside the form triggers a `click` for the sibling button of the checked input when clicked. Any help to get me started appreciated. My markup: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0quo3s7m/1/)

Comment: `$(':radio').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').find('button').trigger('click');
});
`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/0quo3s7m/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#finalbutton').on('click', function(w) {

  $('input:radio:checked').siblings('button').click(); //get the sibling button and click it manually

    w.preventDefault();
});

$('div button').on('click', function(w) {

  console.log($(this).text())
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/0quo3s7m/6/)

I added a prevent default to avoid the from submitting(for checking only) check the console for the button that is triggered. I also added an `ID` for the final  button.

Comment: Thanks guradio, spot on :)

Comment: glad to help happy coding mate :)